# javascript error with label

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a function as follows:

```
function textNext(element, num) {
    document.getElementById("lblContent").innerHTML = "hello";
}
```

However, the text of the `lblContent` label won't change when the function is called.

What am I doing wrong?

btw : lblContent is of type asp:Label

Comment: why do you pass element parameter to this function, may be your call is wrong?

Comment: Have you checked your browsers error console? Also, you should check that your element's id attribute is correctly spelt and capitalised.

Comment: Looks fine to me.  As "ar" says check the simple stuff.  If nothing obvious jumps out stick in the classic debug alert.  Maybe "alert('element = ' + document.getElementById("lblContent"))".  This will confirm that the method is being called and that the element lblContent exists.

Comment: Is this an ASP.NET server side label control?

Comment: yes it is an asp.net server side label

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `lblControl` is a *server side* ASP.NET control, you will need to use the control [`ClientID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx) property in order to use it in javascript:

```
function textNext(element, num) {
    document.getElementById(<"%=lblContent.ClientID%>").innerHTML = "hello";
}
```

Comment: this gives a 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label' does not contain a definition for 'ClientId' error.

Answer (score 0):

Check the console in your browser for errors. I tried to reproduce your problem in a standard HTML/Javascript environment.

This works for me.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    <head>
    <body>
        <div id="lblContent">Previous text</div>

        <a href="#" onclick="textNext()">Change text</a>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function textNext() {
                document.getElementById("lblContent").innerHTML = "Next text";
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```